# [Vue warn]: Property "handleCreateClick" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: laravel, vue.js, modal-dialog

The app is in laravel, vuejs. Used Laravel breeze for some functionalities. For a feature, a button should open a modal. But modal not opened, The error in the console -
`[Vue warn]: Property "handleCreateClick" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance`
No hit in the button specific actions in the vue devtool

Vuecode -

```
<template>
    <div v-if="showDialog">
        <div>
            <input v-model="taskName" type="text" id="taskName" placeholder="Task Name" required/>
            <template v-if="projects.length === 0">
            <input v-model="projectName" type="text" id="projectName" placeholder="Project Name" required/>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
            <select v-model="projectName" id="projectName" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Project Name</option>
                <option v-for="project in projects" :value="project.id" :key="project.id">{{ project.name }}</option>
            </select>
            </template>
            <template v-if="users.length === 0">
            <input v-model="assignedTo" type="text" id="assignedTo" placeholder="Assigned To" required/>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
            <select v-model="assignedTo" id="assignedTo" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Assigned To</option>
                <option v-for="user in users" :value="user.id" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }}</option>
            </select>
            </template>
            <select v-model="priority" id="priority" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Priority Level</option>
            <option value="High">High</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Low">Low</option>
            </select>
            <select v-model="taskStatus" id="taskStatus" @change="handleTaskStatusChange" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Task Status</option>
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="Working On">Working On</option>
            <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
            </select>
            <input v-model="taskStartTime" type="datetime-local" id="taskStartTime" placeholder="Select Start Time" required/>
            <input v-model="taskDueTime" type="datetime-local" id="taskDueTime" placeholder="Select Due Time" required/>
            <input v-model="taskCompletedTime" :disabled="taskStatus !== 'Completed'" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Select Completed Time" id="taskCompletedTime"/>
            <textarea v-model="taskDescription" id="taskDescription" placeholder="Task Description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button @click="createTask">Create</button>
        <button @click="showDialog = false">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
export default {
    name: 'taskcreate',
    data() {
        return {
            showDialog: false,
            taskName: '',
            projectName: '',
            priority: '',
            assignedTo: '',
            taskStatus: '',
            taskStartTime: '',
            taskDueTime: '',
            taskCompletedTime: '',
            taskDescription: '',
            projects: [],
            users: [],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.fetchUsers();
      this.fetchProjects();
      this.handleTaskChange();
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchUsers() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('/api/users');
                this.users = response.data;
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching Users:', error);
                alert('Error fetching Users');
            }
        },
        async fetchProjects() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('/api/projects');
                this.projects = response.data;
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching projects:', error);
                alert('Error fetching Projects');
            }
        },
        async createTask() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('/api/tasks/create', {
                    taskName: this.taskName,
                    projectName: this.projectName,
                    priority: this.priority,
                    assignedTo: this.assignedTo,
                    taskStatus: this.taskStatus,
                    taskStartTime: this.taskStartTime,
                    taskDueTime: this.taskDueTime,
                    taskCompletedTime: this.taskCompletedTime,
                    taskDescription: this.taskDescription,
                });
                console.log('Creating task');
                console.log(response.data);
                this.showDialog = false;
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('Error creating task:', error.response.data);
            }
        },
        async handleTaskChange() {
            if (this.taskStatus === 'Completed') {
                this.taskCompletedTime = format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            }
        },
        async handleCreateClick() {
            console.log('Create button clicked');
            this.showDialog = true;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

app.js code -

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import taskcreate from '../views/components/vue-components/task-create.vue';
const app = createApp({
    components: {
        'taskcreate': taskcreate,
    },
});
app.mount('#app');

// import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
// window.Alpine = Alpine;
// Alpine.start();
```

app.blade.php, include portion -

```
            <div id="app">
                <main>
                    {{ $slot }}
                </main>
            </div>
```

dashboard.blade.php, button code -

```
                        <div class="px-6 pt-4 pb-2">
                            <button @click="handleCreateClick" class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">Create</button>
                            <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2"><a href="#">show</a></span>
                            <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2"><a href="#">createv</a></span>
                        </div>
            <taskcreate></taskcreate>
```

Trying to make modal open and work the functionality. Hope i get help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means that the function `handleCreateClick` is not created or not in the right place at least

Comment: function is created and in the right place in the vue file

Comment: But you don't seem to call it within the vue file

Comment: please check the method part. Also if i add it in the mounted, it showed automatically without button click

Comment: Your function is indeed in the vue file but the button that calls it is not so it do not have access to it.  You need to move the function in the button component or you can access it with ref component

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleCreateClick` function is defined in the `taskcreate` element and thus cannot be called from the "parent" element containing the `taskcreate`.

To call the `handleCreateClick` from the `dashboard.blade.php` button code, you have to change your code and define a proper handler in `dashboard.blade.php`

```
<div class="px-6 pt-4 pb-2">
    <button @click="handleCreateClickFromDashboard" class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">Create</button>
    <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2"><a href="#">show</a></span>
    <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2"><a href="#">createv</a></span>
</div>
<taskcreate ref="taskCreate"></taskcreate>

[...other code...]

[...jump to methods definition...]
handleCreateClickFromDashboard () {
   // the taskcreate element has a ref called 'taskCreate'
   // -> call the vuejs this.$refs special var to get the 'taskCreate' element
   //    and call the handleCreateClick() method defined in the element
   this.$refs.taskCreate.handleCreateClick()
}
```

Documentation about `$refs` can be found [here](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#refs)